# dompdf: Blank pdf output

Tags: php, html, dom, dompdf

I've been using dompdf for my application, but after switch my server I've been getting blank output. After I turned on debug I got following error.

```
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: div and table in Entity, 
line: 131 DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: div and table in Entity, line: 132 DOMDocument::
loadHTML(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: div and table in Entity, line: 133
Unable to stream pdf: headers already sent
```

Code that it is referring to as follows

```
<tr style="border:2px solid lightgray;border-right:none;border-left:none;border-top:none;">
                        <th style="width:33.333333333333333%;text-align:left;">Activity</th>
                        <th style="width:16.666666666666666%;text-align:left;">Hours</th>
                        <th style="width:25%;text-align:left;">Rate</th>
                        <th style="width:25%;text-align:right;">Line Total</th>
                    </tr>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot is advance.

Comment: `div and table`. you're missing a `</div>` or `</table>` somewhere...

Comment: Thank you Marc, I was able to add the missing tags, but the output is still and there are no more warnings.

Comment: It would help to see a more complete sample. You might try running your HTML through a [validator](https://validator.w3.org) to see if anything else needs to be fixed. If you're using v0.6.x you can call `$dompdf->output_html()` to see what the working document looks like. And if you enable the HTML5 parser it will try to fix any HTML syntax errors.

Comment: Also, if you moved from one server to another and are using the exact same code it may be a server configuration issue. Maybe the font references in the dompdf_font_family_config file are incorrect? Maybe a PHP extension is missing? Try a simpler document to see if dompdf is at least functioning.

Comment: Thanks Brain, really appreciate the help. I am using v0.6x and here is the rendering code that I am using `$pdfContent = $pdfContent->render('pdf', 'ajax');
  //echo $pdfContent;
  //die();
  
  
  require_once("../Lib/dompdf-master/dompdf_config.inc.php");
  $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
  $dompdf->load_html($pdfContent);
  $dompdf->render();
  $pdf = $dompdf->stream("Invoice.pdf", array('Attachment' => 0));

Comment: Is there a way for me to know what php extension I might be missing if any ?

Comment: I tried rendering a simple file, still a blank page.

Comment: This may take some back-and-forth ... let's continue the discussion on the [dompdf support forum](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/dompdf/KDW9j2sQow4/discussion)